# Find last column assigned in Range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I need to find out the column that is the last column in a range that is defined with:

```
Set RngSource = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

Comment: `RngSource.Columns(RngSource.Columns.Count).Column`

Comment: See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/11/09/find-last-column-in-an-excel-sheet-vbavb-net/)

Answer (score 1):

First things first

Never use `UsedRange` to set your range. I have explained it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) as to why you shouldn't use `UsedRange`

```
Set RngSource = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

Find the Last Column that has data and the Last Row which has data and then set your range. So your question of finding the last column from the range will not arise. Here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    '~~> Set your worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Find Last Row
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row

            '~~> Find Last Column
            lCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                   After:=.Range("A1"), _
                   Lookat:=xlPart, _
                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                   MatchCase:=False).Column
        Else
            lRow = 1: lCol = 1
        End If

        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))

        Debug.Print rng.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use End(xlToRight) with an activecell.

Comment: This is the wrong way of doing it :) Imagine if the Activecell is in the last column?

Comment: Excellent point...I always forget about 'Find'. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.