# Populate Variable with all values in Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a variable with all the cell values in used columns in Row 1.

```
Dim vaData As Variant

With wsSheet
vaData = .Range("B1:" & .Range(.Columns.Count & "1").End(xlRight).Column).Value
End With
```

I am getting a range failed error.

I have successfully done this for getting values in a column, BK.

```
vaData = .Range(.Range("BK2"), .Range("BK100").End(xlUp)).Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim vaData As Variant

With wsSheet
    vaData = .Range("B1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With
```

The thing is you might have been confused between *Range Object* and *Cells Property*.
Refer to below *Range Object Syntax* I frequently use:

- Range("Cell1", "Cell2") e.g. `Range("A1", "A10")`
- Range("Cell1:Cell2") e.g. `Range("A1:A10")`
- Range(Cells(1),Cells(2)) e.g. `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 1))`

Above all evaluates to *Range A1:A10*. Now how to make it dynamic?

**Examples:**

Dynamic Last Row

```
With Sheet1
    .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) '~~> dynamic last row
    .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) '~~> same as above
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '~~> same as above
End With
```

Dynamic Last Column

```
With Sheet1
    .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) '~~> same as my answer
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) '~~> same as above
End With
```

Btw, [another more complex approach is found here using *Find Method.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)
The same approach [was used here to find the last column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309197/find-last-column-assigned-in-range).
Also you might want to check [different ways on using *Cells Property*.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485791/excel-vba-paste-problems/20487279#20487279)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that in the first example you are missing the column letter i.e. the formula will evaluate to something like

```
vaData =.Range("B1:10").Value 'Error!
```

Instead of

```
vaData =.Range("B1:B10").Value 'Ok!
```

Hope this helps...